# Different behaviour running a script from Powershell ISE and Windows Explorer

Tags: powershell

Why does my command behaves differently when I run it from the Windows Explorer and from ISE?

I have a simple command from Test1.ps1 (both Test1 and Test2 are in the same folder)

```
& ".\Test2.ps1"
```

When I run it from Windows explorer, the script Test2.ps1 is executed. However, when I run it in ISE it doesnt work and I get the following error:

> & : Die Benennung ".\Test2.ps1" wurde nicht als Name eines Cmdlet, einer Funktion, einer Skriptdatei oder eines ausführbaren Programms erkannt. Überprüfen Sie die Schreibweise des Namens, oder ob der Pfad korrekt
> ist (sofern enthalten), und wiederholen Sie den Vorgang.
> In Zeile:1 Zeichen:3
> +& ".\Test2.ps1"
>
> - CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (.\Test2.ps1:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Sorry for the german: it basically says: ".\Test2.ps1" was not found as a name of a cmdlet, a function, a script file or an executed programm. check the typing of the name or if the path is correct

Comment: The PowerShell ISE is [no longer actively developed](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/components/ise/introducing-the-windows-powershell-ise#support) and [there are reasons not to use it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134096/45375) (bottom section), notably not being able to run PowerShell [Core] 6+. The actively developed editor that offers the best PowerShell development experience, across platforms, is [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/), combined with its [PowerShell extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the working directory shown in the script pane.
ISE usually starts on your user profile.
Either change to the path of your script first.

```
Set-Location -Path "C:\ScriptLocation\"
```

Or use the full path when you call the script:

```
& "C:\ScriptLocation\Test2.ps1"
```

When you run it from Explorer, PowerShell is starting on the same folder which is why it is able to find the script.